# What is instability in the context of fluid dynamics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, turbulence

I have been reading a paper about the production of respiratory droplets in human respiratory tract and learned that they are produced due to instabilities, which includes the Rayleigh Taylor instability. Wikipedia contains examples about Rayleigh instability but I couldn't understand what instability means in the context of fluid dynamics.

In the paper, it says air brushing with the mucus has certain instabilities and this creates mucal fragments. How can this be related to Rayleigh instability? And what does instability mean in context of fluid dynamics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any dynamical system an instability occurs when small perturbations to an equilibrium state grow exponentially and drive the system away from equilibrium. The opposite of an instability is a stable equilibrium, where perturbations decay exponentially. A cone balanced on its apex is an example of unstable equilibrium; a cone sat on its base is an example of stable equilibrium.

In fluid dynamics an instability is characterised by a move away from smooth laminar flow to turbulent flow, where the velocity field of the flow changes rapidly and chaotically in both time and space, and large shear forces are generated. When there is turbulent flow over a surface, these shear forces can pick up small particles or droplets from the surface and transport them as an aerosol.

Comment: In the case of Rayleigh or Taylor instability, for example, there are two exact laminar flow solutions to the flow equations, but only one of these solutions is stable, and any perturbation to the less stable solution causes a transition to the more stable flow.